# ¿porque se declara, pero su valor no se lee nunca. los elementos dentro de los Route en react con router dom 6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Como se ve en la imagen anexa, los componentes {navBar} y {searchBar}  no se leen nunca y no se renderizan.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

siguiendo los pasos equivalentes a los procesos de una ruta, encuentro el inconveniente por el cual no se renderizan los componentes dentro de los elementos. ¿cual es la razón a este problema y como se podría solucionar?

INDEX

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';
 
ReactDOM.render(
  
    <App />
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

APP

```
import { AppRouter } from "./components/routers/AppRouter"
 
export const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
         <AppRouter/>   
        </>
    )
}
```

NAVBAR

```
export const navBar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>prueba barra de navegación</h1>    
        </div>
    )
}
```

SEARCH

```
export const searchBar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>prueba search bar</h1>    
        </div>
    )
}
```

APPROUTER

```
import {  Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { navBar } from "../navbar/navBar";
import { searchBar } from "../searchbar/searchBar";
export const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <h1>PRUEBA INICIAL</h1>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<navBar />}/>
            <Route path="/search" element={<searchBar />}/>
 
        </Routes>
            
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Comment: ¿Y que tal si cambia el nombre de los componentes con Mayúscula en la primera letra? `NavBar - SearchBar`

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias,  a que se debe este problema?

Comment: la respuesta en el  enlace, los componentes en jsx con letra minúscula se leen como etiquetas html. 

https://qastack.mx/programming/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Los nombres de los componentes ReactJS deben comenzar con letras mayúsculas.

Como se indica en una [respuesta de QA Stack](https://qastack.mx/programming/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters):

> - `<component />`compila a `React.createElement('component')` (etiqueta html)
> - `<Component />` compila a `React.createElement(Component)`
> - `<obj.component />` compila a `React.createElement(obj.component)`

Comment: Podrías haber escrito un comentario en tu misma publicación, como tal, esto no es considerado una respuesta. Además, evita en lo más que puedas incluír enlaces externos que no sean una documentación o referencia.